# When should I consider using polynomial regression instead of linear regression?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I have a dataset and I'm trying to determine when it is appropriate to apply polynomial regression for modeling the relationship between variables. I have already performed exploratory data analysis and identified a potential nonlinear pattern in the data.
I would appreciate any insights or best practices for handling datasets where polynomial regression may be a suitable approach. If you have any code examples, tutorials, or recommended resources related to applying polynomial regression in Python, please share them as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.